# Cypress - If Else based on Presence of element without throwing 'Expected to find element: but never found it.'

Tags: javascript, if-statement, xpath, cypress

While using Cypress - I would like to understand ways to do action vs not do action based on element found or not.
I tried all below with help from Google search - but ended up with just a bunch of hours wasted:

1. `cy.xpath('').then($ele => {})` - throws Timed out retrying after 20000ms: Expected to find element: //div[text()='hello']//div, but never found it.
2. `cy.xpath('').then(ele => { eleLenght = Cypress.$(ele).length})` - throws Timed out retrying after 20000ms: Expected to find element: //div[text()='hello']//div, but never found it.
3. `cy.xpath('').then($ele => {}).catch({})` - catch is not defined
4. `cy.xpath('').its('lenght').then($ele => {})` - throws Timed out retrying after 20000ms: Expected to find element: //div[text()='hello']//div, but never found it.
5. `cy.xpath('').should('be:visisble').then($ele => {})` - throws Timed out retrying after 20000ms: Expected to find element: //div[text()='hello']//div, but never found it.

My case: If an element is present - I want to try to delete it, but if not present - gracefully continue without throwing the annoying error as above!

Can someone please help here?
Conditional testing doc provided in cypress does'nt help at all!

Comment: I know you will not like this comment but cypress does not want you to test in this way, its better to be deterministic and to control your current application state instead of deciding what to do based in presence of elements

Comment: Ah! Isn't this making the whole process a more of handicap than enabling?
Because - for a CI retry - I would like to verify that element is not already present before creating [bcs we ve internal validation while creating a duplicate entity] hence delete it if its present - then proceed with creation.

How do I even achieve this then!

Comment: why would there be an element already present ? Is it from a previous test? or its random ?

Comment: It is from previous run.

Comment: are you running tests on some running test server ? Please check https://docs.cypress.io/guides/getting-started/testing-your-app#Step-1-Start-your-server

Mainly this part : 

Why start a local development server?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it with jquery notation:

```
if (Cypress.$("#your-element-id").length > 0) {
    //do something
} else {
    //do nothing
}
```

Have you tried below?

```
cy.xpath('').should('have.length.gt',0).then($ele => {console.log($ele)})
```

Comment: Nope, my element does not have an id. Its a complex xpath -
 ```//div[text()='" +
    entityName +
    "']/ancestor::div[contains(@class, 't--entity')]//span[contains(@class, 'entity-context-menu')]//div"```

Comment: Can you provide a bit of html?

Comment: Its a bit complex structure... But basically - the need is - to proceed if the element is not present & i'm finding my element via a cy.xpath!

Comment: see edit in answer

Comment: Oh yeah - I have.. Also tried - .should('not.have.length', 0) - but it fails in cy.xpath() already with error as mentioned in point '5' of the question.